# How to get a data from an URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

An API like `http://www.yourWebService.com/PIP.jsp?request=aaa&param=2`

Lets consider the above API gives an JSON value. I use the below coding to get that JSON:

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourWebService.com/PIP.jsp?request=aaa&param=2"];

NSString *resultedString=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

It returns the `JSON` to the `resultedString` variable. It is somewhat small amount of Data.
If that API has large amount of data like in 100's of KB's then whether this coding will work fine, or It will crash?

Answer (score 0):

Many APIs like this generally limit the responses - for example, the twitter API will not return more than 1500 results.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JSON responses from web server you can use JSON parser to get the results in the form of `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Better you should go with ASIHTTPRequest class which wrapper around NSUrlRequest , following links will be useful

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest-CFNetwork-wrapper-for-HTTP-requests